# Django ConnectionRefusedError [Errno 111] Connection refused facing issue how to solve it

Tags: django

I'm facing issue when send mail on django **[Errno 111] Connection refused**
my setting.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'  # Replace with your preferred backend

EMAIL_HOSTS = 'smtp.gmail.com'  # Replace with your email host

EMAIL_PORT = 587  # Replace with your email port

EMAIL_USE_TLS = config('EMAIL_USE_TLS', cast=bool)  # Set to False if your email server doesn't use TLS

EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')  # Replace with your email username

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')  # Replace with your email password
```

view.py

```
current_url = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = "Please activate your account."
            message = render_to_string('base/pass/account_verify.html',{
                'user':user,
                'domain':current_url,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token':default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = email
            send_mail = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            send_mail.send()
```

i have check all mail setting.py but can't solve this error on local it's work but when i am production and host while it's not working and get this error

Comment: Provide error in your question. Please check your connection details.

Comment: If you provide your Gmail password, it will not work. Please make sure to use the app password instead.